# Specialized Sirrus specs any ok?

Tags: road-bike

I can get this bike for good price, bit I was wondering of the specs are "okay"?
And does anyone have any experience with it?

[specs. sheet (image)](http://f.cl.ly/items/172F11272A0G3A020K3x/img092.jpg)

Comment: The scan is kind of a pain to read. Is that a [2011 Sirrus](http://www.specialized.com/us/en/bc/SBCProduct.jsp?arc=2011&spid=52891)?

Comment: Your question is too vague.  Without more information on what type of riding you'd like to do, there's no way we can give you feedback on the whether or not it's a good bike for you.  Unless your question is "is the Specialized Sirrus such a terrible bike that it wouldn't be good for anyone at any price?" and the answer to that is "no"

Comment: @freiheit I think its the 2012 because the 2011 has a curved frame.

prototoast: i will used it to ride to work 10km each day, at the moment I only have an old canondale.

Answer (score 2):

Almost every modern bike that retails for over $300 USD is *okay*, in terms of parts spec. I've ridden and worked on sirruses (sirri?) and they don't seem particularly different from other bikes in the genre. Ride it, and if it feels good and the price is right, buy it.